# what does SQL @x := @x +1 and @x := 0 mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was doing rank score problem at leetcode and I am not sure below solution. I can understand every part except for `@x := @x +1` and `@x := 0`.

```
select scores.score, ranks.rank from scores left join (
    select score, @x := @x +1 as rank from (select distinct score from scores order by score desc) s, (select @x := 0) r
) 
as ranks on scores.score = ranks.score order by scores.score desc;
```

Anyone could help please?

Comment: That's a nasty hack in MySQL to "count" in order to simulate a `ROW_NUMBER/RANK` function. Search SO for "mysql row_number" or "mysql rank". What makes this approach a 'nasty hack' is that it bleeds a side-effect of increment'ing (`@x := @x + 1`) and resetting a counter (`@x := 0`).

Comment: @user2864740 a hack it may be, but there's nothing nasty about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare a var `@x` initialization it as int `0`

```
select @x := 0
```

---

When you doing `select` clause the `@x` will add `1`.

```
select @x := @x +1
```

Here is a sample

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   col1 varchar(51)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('TEST');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('TEST1');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  *,@x:=@x +1
FROM T  CROSS JOIN (select @x := 0) v;

| col1  | @x := 0 | @x:=@x +1 |
| ----- | ------- | --------- |
| TEST  | 0       | 1         |
| TEST1 | 0       | 2         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fzK1zRDvQfJWKevWwp1vBE/0)

**NOTE**

```
select score, @x := @x +1 as rank 
from (select distinct score from scores order by score desc) s, (select @x := 0) r
```

- the  `,` comma between two tables in the query means `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: so use `cross join` don't use the comma bad habit